# Troubles in building singed apk again in EXPO

Tags: android, apk, store, keystore, expo

Everybody.
I have a trouble to build signed apk again for upgrading version from 1.0 to 1.1.

Followings are what i did.

1. First i built an apk by choosing 1) Let Expo handle the process!.
2. And then uploaded the apk to google store.
3. Nowdays, i have to upgrade the version, but i don't have any keystore file.

These are what i tried to do.

1. Downloaded upload_cert.der file from Google store.
2. Created a keystore file by this command 
   **`keytool.exe -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore <keystorefile>.keystore`**
3. Built an apk by choosing 2) I want to upload my own keystore!
4. But can't install the apk with an error.
   When i run this command **`keytool -printcert -jarfile <apkname>.apk`**, 
   this message appears **`Not a signed jar file`**

So Could you everybody let me know please...

1. Is this really impossible to upgrade apk without original keystore
2. Or how to create a correct keystore from upload_cert.der file

Thanks.